Removing "doi: " from my references
I am working to finalize my references for a paper but I cannot figure out how to remove something from each reference. For example a current reference looks like this:

Artemieva, I. M. (2019). Lithosphere thermal thickness and geothermal heat flux
in greenland from a new thermal isostasy method. Earth-Science Reviews, 188,
469–481. doi: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.earscirev.2018.10.015

The underlying entry in the bib file looks like this:
@article{Artemieva2019,
    abstract = {},
    author = {Artemieva, Irina M. },
    date = {2019/01/01/},
    date-added = {2024-01-21 16:26:00 -0500},
    date-modified = {2024-01-21 16:26:00 -0500},
    doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.earscirev.2018.10.015},
    isbn = {0012-8252},
    journal = {Earth-Science Reviews},
    keywords = {Lithosphere thickness; Iceland hotspot; Cratonic mantle; 
        Continental crust; Kimberlite; Mantle temperature},
    pages = {469--481},
    title = {Lithosphere thermal thickness and geothermal heat
        flux in Greenland from a new thermal isostasy method},
    url = {},
    volume = {188},
    year = {2019},
    bdsk-url-1 = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012825218304847},
    bdsk-url-2 = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.earscirev.2018.10.015}}

I want to remove the "doi: " prefix string before the link, so that the formatted entry looks like this:

Artemieva, I. M. (2019). Lithosphere thermal thickness and geothermal heat flux
in greenland from a new thermal isostasy method. Earth-Science Reviews, 188,
469–481. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.earscirev.2018.10.015

I am using these packages and I am unable to use other bibliography packages due to the requirements of the journal:
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[inline]{trackchanges} 
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\linenumbers

Edit:
This is a minimal example without the actual text of the document:
\documentclass[draft]{agujournal2019}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[inline]{trackchanges} 
\usepackage{soul} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\linenumbers 
\draftfalse
\journalname{JGR: Solid Earth}

\begin{document}

...

\bibliography{thesisbib} 
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE. We'll need more information to be able to address your issue fully, i.e., a full but minimal version of your document code and bibliography file that reproduces the current behavior. However, you could try to change the doi field in the .bib file to url for all of your references, that might be sufficient to change the output.

Unfortunately when I use url instead it prints as: RETRIEVED FROM https://doi.org which I still cannot have. I will try to get a full version.

@Marijn I have added the section of the .bib file that produces that reference. The only time that I do anything within the main script in reference to the bibliography is when I call it at the end with: \bibliography{thesisbib}

Maybe howpublished = {\url{https://doi.org/10.1016/j.earscirev.2018.10.015}} would work. But instead of guessing it would be better if you provide a complete document so it can actually be tested.

What bibliography package are you using? What journal is this? Can you provide a minimal example that replicates your current setup? It should start with \documentclass and end with \end{document}. Can you do that?

@Werner I have added the minimal example. The journal is AGU, specifically JGR: Solid Earth so I use their template. THank you any help you can provide.

@DeanW: It would be better if you can provide their template files. Where does one find that?

Related/duplicate: using APA6 style with current DOI specifications

agujournal2019 currently employs the apacite package to manage the bibliography content. From the apacite documentation you can update \doiprefix (default is dio:) to suit your needs.
The following document uses the default article class, but showcases what you need to do.

%\documentclass{agujournal2019}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{apacite}% Used by agujournal2019
\bibliographystyle{apacite}% Set by agujournal2019

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{thesisbib.bib}
@article{Artemieva2019,
    abstract = {},
    author = {Artemieva, Irina M. },
    date = {2019/01/01/},
    date-added = {2024-01-21 16:26:00 -0500},
    date-modified = {2024-01-21 16:26:00 -0500},
    doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.earscirev.2018.10.015},
    isbn = {0012-8252},
    journal = {Earth-Science Reviews},
    keywords = {Lithosphere thickness; Iceland hotspot; Cratonic mantle; Continental crust; Kimberlite; Mantle temperature},
    pages = {469--481},
    title = {Lithosphere thermal thickness and geothermal heat flux in {Greenland} from a new thermal isostasy method},
    url = {},
    volume = {188},
    year = {2019},
    bdsk-url-1 = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012825218304847},
    bdsk-url-2 = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.earscirev.2018.10.015}}
\end{filecontents*}

\renewcommand{\doiprefix}{\ignorespaces}% Remove DOI prefix

\begin{document}

\cite{Artemieva2019}

\bibliography{thesisbib}

\end{document}


+1. You beat me to the solution (modifying \doiprefix) by a minute. Don't forget to encase the work "Greeland" in curly braces, though. :-)

@Mico: Great suggestion, thanks!

This worked perfectly! Thanks so much. Very helpful and straightforward fix
